# Delphi XE6 Component package issue. Can't compile project

Tags: delphi, indy

Using `Rewrite` I was getting an error

> E2158 System unit out of date or corrupted: missing '@assign'.

So I exited, and renamed my `.dproj` file.  Once the new `.dproj` was generated, I tried to compile my project again.  Now I'm getting an error

> E2202 Required package 'indy' not found.

I checked my Indy package and it's installed.  I uninstalled it, and reinstalled, but no change.  If I go into Component->Install Packages... and scroll down to the Indy 10 Core Design Time and/or Indy 10 Protocols Design Time and highlight one, then click the Edit button I get an error

> Unable to edit package dclindyprotocols200.bpl. The source could not be found.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Check and correct your path settings: Environment variables, library paths and search paths.

Comment: @nolaspeaker - Yeah, I checked and it all looked good, and to my knowledge none of those things should have changed other than possibly the path getting added to recently.  I did notice that the path length was 1,454 characters long.  Is there a maximum length for that?

Comment: Indy 10 doesn't have any package named "indy". Its packages are "IndySystemXXX", "IndyCoreXXX", "IndyProtocolsXXX", "dclIndyCoreXXX", and "dclIndyProtocolsXXX" (`XXX` is the IDE's package version, where `200` corresponds to XE6).  Your project should not have any reference to an "indy" package in it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Okay, I removed the references to "indy" in my packages, and now I'm back to the `E2158` error message.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a corrupted IDE installation.  Did you try reinstalling it yet?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - No, I was hoping not to have to.